# python requests: POST запрос c изображением

Tags: python, изображения, post, requests

Сломал уже всю голову помогите пожалуйста, cайт https://www.imgonline.com.ua/stereoscopic-3d-picture-from-photo.php, пытаюсь немного автоматизировать конвертацию изображений, но никак не получается заполучить конвертированное изображение запросом. Запрос должен быть таким, насколько я понял:

```
    382535001020948189383489982291
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadfile"; filename="image.jpg"
    Content-Type: image/jpeg
    
    
    -----------------------------382535001020948189383489982291
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="efset1"
    
    1
    -----------------------------382535001020948189383489982291
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="efset2"
    
    15
    -----------------------------382535001020948189383489982291
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="efset3"
    
    10
    -----------------------------382535001020948189383489982291
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="efset4"
    
    1
    -----------------------------382535001020948189383489982291
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="outformat"
    
    2
    -----------------------------382535001020948189383489982291
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="jpegtype"
    
    1
    -----------------------------382535001020948189383489982291
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="jpegqual"
    
    95
    -----------------------------382535001020948189383489982291--
```

Мой неработающий код сейчас, но выглядит так:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    
    headers = {
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
    }
    image = open('i.jpg', 'rb')
    files = {'upload_file': image}
    
    data = {
        'efset1': 1,
        'efset2': 15,
        'efset3': 10,
        'efset4': 1,
        'outformat': 2,
        'jpegtype': 1,
        'jpegqual': 95,
    }
    with requests.session() as s:
        res = s.post(
            'https://www.imgonline.com.ua/stereoscopic-3d-picture-from-photo-result.php',
            headers=headers,
            files=files,
            data=data
        )
    
    html = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    
    with open('src.html', 'w') as file:
        file.write(html.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в том, что вы неправильно указали в словаре files ключ `upload_file`. Нужно было посмотреть в инспекторе, какой `name` требовалось передать.

[image]
Как видно из изображения выше, в качестве значения нужно было передать `uploadfile`, а не `upload_file`.

Я тут написал самый простенький код, который скачивает только 1 картинку, думаю вы уже сможете дописать код, чтоб у каждой картинки было свое индивидуальное имя.

Пример ниже:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36 '
}
with open('test.jpg', 'rb') as image:
    files = {'uploadfile': image.read()}

data = {
    'efset1': 1,
    'efset2': 15,
    'efset3': 10,
    'efset4': 1,
    'outformat': 2,
    'jpegtype': 1,
    'jpegqual': 95,
}
with requests.session() as s:
    res = s.post(
        'https://www.imgonline.com.ua/stereoscopic-3d-picture-from-photo-result.php',
        headers=headers,
        files=files,
        data=data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
    url = soup.find_all("a")
    img = s.get(url[8].get('href'))
    with open('myphoto.jpg', 'wb') as photo:
        photo.write(img.content)
```